# Java Generic Type Arguments not validated

Tags: java, generics

I am just wondering, why the assignment of a wrong type value does not lead to any runtime exception. I prepared a little example, where class X holds a generic variable "object" that implements Interface A and class Y declares this generic to be of type B

```
public interface A{};
public class B implements A{}
public class C implements A{}
public class X<T extends A>{
  T object;
  void setObject(T t){
    object = t;
  }
  T getObject(){
   return object;
  }
}
public class Y extends X<B>{}
```

If I have a variable of type X holding and Y-Object, the compiler allows the assignment of any value, which is correct from my opinion. But at runtime, I would expect an exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  X<A> foo = (X<A>) Class.forName("com.abc.Y").newInstance();
  foo.setObject(new B()); //should not fail
  foo.setObject(new C()); //should fail
}
```

I don't get any exceptions, until class Y, tries to access the object.

If I add this method to class Y, I get a ClassCastException on setObject, but I actually don't want to override all Methods with the correct Class.

```
public class Y extends X<B>{
  void setObject(B t){
    super.setObject(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: `X` is a raw type. Parameterize it.

Comment: as i use reflection to create the object Y and the Object of type A, i am not sure, how to correctly parameterize it.

Comment: `X<String> x = new Y();`

Comment: I edited the question, it is not about strings anymore. the problem is that any object involved is created via reflection.

Comment: Why should `foo.setObject(new C());` fail at compile time? `C` is an `A`.

Comment: i want it to fail on runtime, cause class 'Y' requires 'object' to be of type 'B'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you're generating the object at runtime [using Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html), while generics are only checked at compile time.

This is due to Java Generics being implemented using [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  That is, they're [not present](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) in the compiled code.

Comment: thank you never heard about so far. In the decompiled code I was able to see it.

Comment: Incidentally, if you use a normal constructor instead of reflection, the compiler should catch that the type is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that behavior is java's type erasure.
Type erasure generally means that all generics are replaced by casting by java (that's why you get ClassCastException).
So this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("text");
String x = list.get(0);
```

will be converted to this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("text");
String x = (String) list.get(0);
```

You can read more about this here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure